# Xcode 10 Not Always Jumps to Location of Warning/Error

Tags: xcode, bug

After upgrading to Xcode 10, I have noticed that for *some* issues (*not* all) the source code editor no longer jumps to the location of a compiler error or warning when I click said issue on the issue navigator.

Any known fix to this? (other than "delete derived data", etc.)

Answer (score 1):

From [Stack Overflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877377/xcode-4-errors-warnings-dont-jump-to-code-when-i-click-them)

> In the left hand panel, click on the "Show the log navigator", its the button which looks like a speech bubble. Now underneath will show the logs for every build. This is like the old Xcode, and will show errors/warnings. When you double click on the errors it will open the file to the line of the error.

Comment: Thank you. No way to fix the **issue** navigator, though?

Comment: @NicolasMiari i don't think there is